# How to get Image name while updating in react js?

Tags: reactjs, django, image

Here I'M trying to create updating feature. I'm getting all the values while editing but i'm not able to get the name of image which was uploaded while creating the post.[image]

How can I get the name of image instead of "No File Choosen"?
[image]

I'm getting data from the backend in this format.

```
setEditInitialState({
    id: data.id,
    meta_title: data.meta_title,
    blog_name: data.blog_name,
    blog_category: {
      value:
        blogCategories.data?.data.find(
          (category) => category.id === data.blog_category
        )?.id || "",
      label:
        blogCategories.data?.data.find(
          (category) => category.id === data.blog_category
        )?.title || "",
    },
    slug: data.slug,
    image: data.image,
```

##Here is the form

```
<div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="">Image</label>
                  <Input
                    type="file"
                    // className="form-control"
                    // value={values.image}
                    name="image"
                    onChange={(event: any) =>
                      setFieldValue("image", event.target?.files[0])
                    }
                  />
                  {/* <p>{initialValues.image}</p> */}

                  <FormikValidationError
                    name="image"
                    errors={errors}
                    touched={touched}
                  />
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
import os

class yourmodel(models.Model):
     #your fields here
     image = models.ImageField(..............)
      
     #new
     @property
     def filename(self):
          return os.path.basename(self.image.name)
```

now you can get the filename using 'yourinstance.filename'.something like this "image: data.filename".

Comment: Can any one help on how to populate file input value and name with previous data in given condition?

Comment: @sudhansubhattarai it is better not to ask a question on a question.if you have a question it is better to ask a new one separately.because with this less people will see your questions.