# How to delete previous uploaded file when a new one gets uploaded using id

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a simple cv upload class for users to upload their resume. It works just fine but when they upload a newer one, the previous won't get deleted.
This is my code:

```
class ResumeDocument(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cvfile = models.FileField(upload_to="documents", null=True, validators= [validate_file_extension])

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.cvfile.name)
```

How can I reach the previous id? id = self.id - 1. Something like that.

This is my views:

```
@login_required
def pdf_resume(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('pdf_resume')
        if 'delete' in request.GET:
            return delete_item(ResumeDocument, request.GET['id'])

    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    documents = ResumeDocument.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if documents:
        form = DocumentForm(instance=documents[0])
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'documents':documents,
    }
    return render(request, 'reg/pdf_resume.html', context)
```

And this is also my HTML code:

```
<form id="document-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'pdf_resume' %}" autocomplete="off" class="ant-form ant-form-horizontal">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <p>{{ form }}</p>
              

                <div class="ant-row-flex" style="margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -10px;"></div>
                <button id="btn_submit" type="submit"
                    class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary"
                    ant-click-animating-without-extra-node="false" style="float: left;"><span>upload</span></button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to save all uploaded CVs for each user and track the last uploaded CV with field `uploaded_on`. You may refer to the below high-level example:

```
class CVFile(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cv_file = models.FileField(upload_to="documents", null=True, validators=[validate_file_extension])
    uploaded_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

class ResumeDocument(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cv_file = models.ForeignKey(CVFile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You will need to amend your `HMTL` and `views.py` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
class ResumeDocument(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cvfile = models.FileField(upload_to="documents", null=True, validators= 
    [validate_file_extension])
```

views.py(i just look is there any resumedocuments for that user if yes so i give him
the form just if he was editing the existing file)

```
@login_required
def pdf_resume(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('pdf_resume')
        if 'delete' in request.GET:
            return delete_item(ResumeDocument, request.GET['id'])

    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    documents = ResumeDocument.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if documents:#new
        form = DocumentForm(instance=documents[0])
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'documents':documents,
    }
    return render(request, 'reg/pdf_resume.html', context)
```

now inside your pdf_resume.html your can just pass the 'form' because you already check if that user has a document or not.

Comment: it wont work. the form only shows documents[0]. but the previous one wont get deleted.

Comment: I need to somehow delete the previous one. we are just adding files and the form only shows docoument[0]

Comment: @Sam my solution works if you use it for the first_time.i mean when a user has not more than 1 document.I assume that you're on developpement now and you are not on production.when you will be on production it will work.

Comment: for the templates, I need to delete all that and add a form with a submit? that's it? should I remove all the other for loops?

Comment: @sam you don't need the for loop ,you just need the form.because you already checks whether this user has a document or not inside your views.

Comment: @sam is it working ?

Comment: no. I logged in as a new user. after the first upload it only shows the first file. it gets uploaded correctly but no matter how much I upload it only shows the first one

Comment: @sam the solution for that is to change your model.change this line user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) to user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE).and do not forget to makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: @sam to create a onetoonefield so that a user can have only one resumedocument.

Comment: it gives me this error:UNIQUE constraint failed: new__reg_resumedocument.user_id

Comment: @sam it means you already have a user with more than one resumedocument.try to delete all resumedocuments.

Comment: and how can I show the file names? after the user uploaded the file. like this? {{user.cvfile.name}}?

Comment: @sam i already answered that question in other post here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400712/15042684

Comment: I added the function like you said on that link. but when I type {{cvfile.filename}} nothing comes up

Comment: @Sam update your question with the models,views and that templates part where you have cvfile.

Comment: check it out. I updated it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237747/discussion-between-amadou-sow-and-sam).